# Why can't I check the sizeof a struct in C? (undeclared error)

Tags: c, struct, sizeof

I am trying to figure out the `sizeof(p)` where `p` is the `struct` defined below; but, when I try and run the following code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

struct p
{
    char x;
    int y;
};

int main()
{
    printf("%d", sizeof(p));
    return 0;
}
```

I receive this error:

```c
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:19:25: error: ‘p’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     printf("%d", sizeof(p));
                         ^
```

I am a beginner in C and I tried to move `p`'s definition into the `main` function, changing the definition of `p`, looking the error up online (none of the posts with the same error answered my question), etc., but I couldn't seem to get it to work. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: `sizeof (struct p)` and use `printf ("sizeof struct p: %zu\n", sizeof (struct p));` (e.g. `p` is a struct tag name, not a declared instance of the struct, so to determine the size of the type `struct p` the entire type must be used and enclosed in parenthesis)

Comment: You can also define your struct like this:
typedef struct { char x;int y;} p; and then sizeof(p) should work. This behavior is different between C and C++ so it can be confusing

Comment: ah thanks that works! If someone could add that as an answer ill accept, i had no idea i was missing something so simple. Btw why do you need to say `struct` before `p` in the `sizeof` call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C (unlike in C++), the `struct p...` construct does not define a new type of variable. It only defines `p` as a particular type of `struct`. So, in order to get the size of that structure, or to declare a variable of that type, you need to use `struct p` to refer to it.

Like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

struct p {
    char x;
    int y;
};

int main()
{
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(struct p));
    // Alternatively ...
    struct p q;
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(q));
    return 0;
}
```

Also, note that you should use the `%zu` format specifier for the `size_t` type.

Comment: Hmm I was just looking into the `%zu` format specifier, i saw that it mentioned `size_t`, so C has its own data type `size_t` for holding the `sizeof` of a data structure?

Comment: @JohnD Yes. See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t).

Comment: This is probably meant for another question but seeing as it's probably trivial, the answer it prints out is `8` instead of `5` (shouldnt it be `1` byte from the `char x` and `4` bytes from the `int y`). Is this an error in the above code or is that because of padding? Do structs pad the `char x` to 4 bytes from 1 byte?

Comment: @JohnD Yes, again. The structure is padded (by default) so that the `int` member is aligned on a 4-byte boundary. You can turn that off in most compilers, or change the padding size.

Comment: `size_t` is an alias for another integer type

Comment: @JohnD See [Why isn't sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member)